# The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated in nopcommerce 3.70

Tags: email, gmail, nopcommerce

I want to send mail to the client in nopcommerce 3.70 but it is getting the error while sending the mail. It shows "`The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required.`" when send email to the client emailid.

Here is my configuration for the emailID in admin panel of nopcommerce

```
Email address : mextra03@gmail.com
Email display name : extra mail
Host : smtp.gmail.com
Port : 587
User : extra mail
Password : xxxxxxxxxx (10 digit of password containing numeric as well as alphabet)
SSL : Enable
```

I saw this related to this question in this forum and also I tried but showing the same issue.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that your password strength is low. as you are using gmail. Turn "Allow less secure apps" setting to ON and it will work
[this](http://www.technologycrowds.com/2015/05/smtp-server-authentication-server-response-5-5-1-Authentication-Required-in-Gmail.html) may help you through the details too

Comment: yes I have turn on of "Allow less secure apps" option in gmail. And also I dont think so that my password containing low strength because from this mail only I can send to the mail in other website. But in nopcommerce only it shows the error.

Answer (score 0):

In nopCommerce email configuration, user is your email address(user name) to authenticate your mail server.
Thus, user should be your email address instead of *extra mail*.

```
User : mextra03@gmail.com
```

Otherwise, it's look proper to me!

Example:

> ```
> Store Admin Email: YourGmailEmailAddress@gmail.com
> Store Admin Email Display Name: YOURSTORENAME OR Any name you want
> Host:  smtp.gmail.com
> Port:  587
> User:  YourGmailEmailAddress@gmail.com
> Password:   PasswordOfYourGmailAccount
> Enable SSL:  Yes [Check Mark]
> Use default credentials: DO NO CHECK , LEAVE IT UN-CHECKED
> ```

**Edit:** from the comment discussion, give a permission to [lesssecureapps](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps)

Comment: set user also as per you say but still shows the same error.

Comment: No. It is disabled.

Comment: how you means....?? I go this url "https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps" and on the allowed less secure app.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158480/discussion-between-s-k-soni-and-div).

Answer (score 0):

Finally got an answer and i.e. want to take the permission from gmail account that it is our mail only[as per the security propose]. This permission link "`Someone just used your password to try to sign in to your account. Google blocked them, but you should check what happened.`" has send by gmail in our access gmail email account and it is happening when we try to send mail by any application and hence from that by taken permission from gmail account we can access to send mail from our gmail account to other email account. Thanks to Mr. @Div to giving me hint.